# Debug program compiled in MS VC++ 2010 Express with gdb

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gdb

Is it possible to build executable with Microsoft Visual C++ Express, so it could be debugged with gdb?

I tried C7 compatible `/Z7` compiler option with `/debug` linker option, but resulting `.pdb` file is not recognized by gdb:

```
(gdb) symbol-file HelloWorldVC.pdb
`HelloWorldVC.pdb': can't read symbols: File format not recognized.
```

Comment: As harper mentioned, I too don't see any advantage of using GDB for debugging. VS is far far ahead.

Comment: In short, no...

Comment: No, not with msvc. However both the GCC and LLVM compilers are available as Windows binaries that can be used to compile to binaries containing the symbols where both gdb and lldb work just fine. Currently there is only limited support for msvc pdb debug files in lldb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDB has a different debug format than Microsoft's compiler. Indeed the PDB format is not documented.
So you can't use the debug information generated by a Microsoft compiler with GDB.

Honestly I can't find any benefit of GDB that I would use it instead of the debugger of Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: The benefit is IDE independence. I don't like Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: @rmflow When indepence is a criteria you shouldn't consider a proprietaty compiler.

Comment: The Microsoft pdb format _IS_ now being [officially documented on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/microsoft-pdb)

Comment: I've never seen an "official documentation" by Microsoft on github. It would be a surprise to find the PDB documented there. Rrading the issues list you find that some code snippets have been released to help understanding. I wouldn't name that neither official nor documentation.

Comment: When debugging an MSVC generated .efi application using VMware gdb stubs, being able to parse pdb files could have been a great help.

Comment: @harper "The majority of content on this repo is presented as actual source files from the VC++ compiler toolset."  _Actual_ source files, posted by _Microsoft Corporation._  Is it even humanly possible to get any more official than that?  What am I missing?  I must be missing something...

Comment: Old question - but I've found this one: https://github.com/lesderid/gdb-msvc