# GDB on windows, trying to set breakpoint, cannot

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, gdb

I compiled a program using MSVC on windows, it was compiled in debug mode with all symbols enabled. I am trying to catch a segfault.

In Linux when a segfault occurs, gdb automatically stops at the offending line and lets you walk up the stack to see what might have caused it. However on windows this is not happening.

I am trying to set a manual breakpoint through the use of

`b <function name>`

But it doesn't work for any function, not even `main`, I also tried tab autocompletion and it doesn't seem to do anything. I am lost.

Comment: Does `break filename:function` or `break filename:linenum` work?

Comment: Or maybe, GDB doesn't work with MSVC compiled code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26846852

Comment: Oh microsoft...

Comment: Can't you use Visual Studio's debugger tool?

Comment: Maybe, begrudgingly... Trying to figure it out as we speak. I was hoping my dev env on windows would be as close to linux as possible. I am not a fan of VS. I just had lots of trouble compiling with gcc on windows due to library binaries being built with MSVC and not gcc.

Comment: Why do you try to link MSVC compiled library to a GCC compiled application? Isn't that library available for GCC as well? It would be simpler to link GCC compiled library to a GCC compiled application.

Comment: I didn't the problem is I have the binaries for those libraries in MSVC, so if I want to use GCC I have to compile all of them, but many are failing to build on this platform with that compiler for reasons that escape me.

Comment: Did you search for those libraries in [MSYS2 packages](https://packages.msys2.org/package/)? If they're there, then you can download prebuilt ones.