# gdb "No debugging symbols found in blender.exe"

Tags: windows, cmake, blender

When I run `build_windows_x64_vc17_Debug\bin>%gdb% blender.exe` I can see this in the gdb-console:

```
Reading symbols from blender.exe...
(No debugging symbols found in blender.exe)
```

I am building Blender from source via `make debug developer ninja`, **am I wrong expecting it to contain debugging symbols?** (The resulting blender.exe has 498MB, if that can be considered a sign of anything.)

**The -g flag?**

On several places I read that one should add -g flag so I added it (and then -ggdb too) into environmental variables:

```
set CFLAGS=-g
set CXXFLAGS=-g
```

...and into blender\CMakeLists.txt right after `project(Blender)`:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g")
```

...and also here in the same file:

```
set(PLATFORM_LINKFLAGS "-g")
set(PLATFORM_LINKFLAGS_DEBUG "-g")
```

...the log is then full of "cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-g'"

**Point to the pdb?**

I also tried `%gdb% --symbols=blender.pdb blender.exe`, no difference.

My platform is Windows 10 with VS2022 binaries/libraries.
I doubt it matters but this is my version of gdb:

```
GNU gdb (GDB; JetBrains IDE bundle; build 145) 10.2
...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26846852/224239) GDB is not compatible with what the MS-compiler creates.

> GDB has a different debug format than Microsoft's compiler. Indeed the PDB format is not documented. So you can't use the debug information generated by a Microsoft compiler with GDB.